# Group a multidimensional array by a Key value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> I have an multi dimensional array i am trying to group the array based on the key value.
>
> So, I'm trying to group them by key but i am not getting to group the
>   array based on the key values.
>
> Below is the original array

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [feature] => AddUser
                        [feature_level] => 1
                        [parent_feature] => 1
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [feature] => EditUser
                        [feature_level] => 1
                        [parent_feature] => 1
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Candidate] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [feature] => AddCandidate
                        [feature_level] => 1
                        [parent_feature] => 4
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Candidate] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [feature] => EditCandidate
                        [feature_level] => 1
                        [parent_feature] => 4
                    )

            )

    )
```

> What i need is

```
   Array (

   [User] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 2
                    [feature] => AddUser
                    [feature_level] => 1
                    [parent_feature] => 1
                    )
          [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 3
                    [feature] => EditUser
                    [feature_level] => 1
                    [parent_feature] => 1
                    )
          )

   [Candidate] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 5
                    [feature] => AddCandidate
                    [feature_level] => 1
                    [parent_feature] => 4
                 )

          [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 5
                    [feature] => EditCandidate
                    [feature_level] => 1
                    [parent_feature] => 4
                 )
          )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with demo. Might help you:

```
// $myArr is your origional array.
$result_arr = [];

array_walk($myArr,function($v,$k) use (&$result_arr){
   $result_arr[key($v)][] = $v[key($v)]; 
});

print_r($result_arr);
```

Click Here for [Demo](https://3v4l.org/3hNjW)

Answer (score 1):

If your initial array is called `$source`, this should do it:

```
$result =[]; //final array
foreach($source as $data){
    $type = key($data); //eg: 'Candidate' or 'User'
    if(!isset($result[$type])) $result[$type]=[];
    $result[$type][] = reset($data);
}
```

[Demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da42276154b4bae0bfb2e7a218d45863d55bda99)

Comment: User and Candidate values fetched from the db is dynamic it is like parent feature and add,edit are like child feature need to map w.r.t parent and child

Comment: You mean there can be more user-types thans 'User' and 'Candidate' ?  Meaning you could also have 'Admin', or 'Mods'...

Comment: yes  and it may also have like User->adduser,User->viewUser->viewResume. Wt to do in this case where
Parent is User its child is View User and view users child is viewresume.
What to do in this case

Comment: Cool. I rewrote my solution to remove hard-coded strings.